# Select selected option not working for some reason =/

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angular, typescript

[[image: Added a gif to show the problem]For some reason the selected select option not showing any value just a blank area only when clicking it it shows the values. ive checked the css files and it seems fine no idea what causes the problem when i remove the [(ngModel)] it works but not getting the values =/

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Company } from '../_models/company';
import { CompanyService } from '../_services/company.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-company',
  templateUrl: './companies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./companies.component.css']
})
export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedCompany: Company;
   companies: Company[];




  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService, private alertify: AlertifyService) { }




  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCompanies();


  }

  async loadCompanies() {
    this.companyService.getCompanies().subscribe((companies: Company[]) => {
      this.companies = companies;

    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  // selectedChangeHandler(event: any) {
  //   this.selectedCompany = event.target.value;
  // }

}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="companies">
 <div  class="col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-2 mt-5 bd-sidebar">
    <label  for="">Select Company</label> 
    <select class="form-control"    [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany"  >
      <option  selected> -- select an option -- </option>

      <option  *ngFor="let value of companies"   [ngValue]="value">{{value.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</ng-container>





<!--Just a test--->
<!-- <select class="form-control col-lg-8" #selectedValue name="selectedValue" id="selectedValue" [(ngModel)]="company" (ngModelChange)="assignCorporationToManage($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let value of companies" [ngValue]="company">{{value.name}}</option>
</select> -->

<ul *ngIf="selectedCompany" class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item">Company name: {{selectedCompany.name}}</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Company address: {{selectedCompany.address}}</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Company estimated revenue: {{selectedCompany.estimatedRevenue}}₪</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know angular but you may directly see the HTML result by inspecting the select element.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: the problem with things like Angular you don't know what they do under the hood, you can see what's the real HTML outputted for the select it maybe prints an empty `<option></option>` at the begining of the select :o

Comment: I cant seem to find anything wrong. =/ so wierd

Comment: I don't understand the description of the problem. In the video, you select the "Dirtx" value and the name and address are displayed. What else should happen?

Comment: You dont see its blank on start? i set it for <option selected >Select something </option> and there is no value of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several issues with your example, so I am going to offer another approach, and explain what I am doing along the way.

In an Angular application, when using two way binding with `[(ngModel)]` on a select, the initially selected option will always be set to the one that matches the value of `ngModel`.

In your example, the initial value for `selectedCompany` is never set, and that is the reason your initial page load displays the menu with nothing selected. You are going to need to set a value onto all of your options, including the first to get this to work.

Now, since you did not provide the structure of your model titled `Company`, I am going to improvise and assume it contains two elements, `name` and `value`. So just remember, you will need to adjust what I have below to match the actual structure of your data.

First, on the option tags in your select in the template, id suggest using the `value` attribute which we will be populating with strings, instead of `ngValue` which is can be used to contain an object or a string. You can obtain the object that contains all of the data you need via the `change` event later.

Let's adjust your template file as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany" (change)="companyChange($event.target.value)">
      <option [value]="'init'">-- select a company --</option>
      <option  *ngFor="let company of companies" [value]="company.value">{{company.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Next, in your component file, lets change that property that we're using for two way binding on your select to be typed as a string:

`selectedCompany:string;`

Next, lets create a new property typed to your model which we will ultimately set to the company selected:

`myCompany:Company;`

Next, set the initially selected option in your component so that '-- select a company --' will display as the initially selected option:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedCompany = 'init';
  this.loadCompanies();
}
```

And lastly, inside the `change` event, you can use the `find()` method to obtain the complete set of data that you need:

```
companyChange(value) {
 this.myCompany = this.companies.find(element => element.value === value);
 console.log("User selected the company:", this.myCompany);
}
```